# Install windows7

Tags: windows-7, system-installation

I had windows7 when I bought my laptop. However, because I want to learn about linux and ubuntu so I decided to install to ubuntu 13.10 in my laptop; but I accidentally overwrote my windows7 as well. I wonder if there is a way to download windows7 image to create a cd or usb bootable from ubuntu? 
I search many websites but seem cant not find a way to solve the problem yet.

Comment: Downloading Windows 7 is not legal in a lot (most?) countries so you will not find an official source. What you should have done was create a Windows installation from the installation you deleted. But this is offtopic.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't a straightforward way to do this.

You can find an [ISO here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/i-do-not-have-windows-7-media-but-i-do-have-my/5ce13741-ac25-4969-ae82-2494726aac1c) for your corresponding version.  Then, use `unetbootin` to burn the DVD to your USB stick.

Another way is to go to the website of your manufacturer and find out if they offer recovery images.   Quite often, recovery images will completely overwrite the entire drive with a completely factory image.

Finally, there are other sources such as torrents, but the legality and authenticity of these ISOs are questionable.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 DVDs are not license specific. So if you have a friend that has an original (not vendor specific) windows install DVD, you could ask to borrow it and install windows with your license (sticker on bottom of the laptop usually).
Otherwise you might have to spend a few bucks to get the system restore DVDs from your laptops manufacturer, they will usually send them to you for a minor fee of a few bucks (maybe 10 or so).

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder if there is a way to download windows7 image to create a cd or usb bootable from ubuntu?

In Holland we are allowed to download the original software and use a key we purchased (one that is on the sticker on the hardware for instance) but are not allowed to use downloaded registration keys or software that was altered to include the key.

So the answer is yes. But you need to find a download on the web of an ISO or of a torrent and ubuntu will happily download the file for you that you can burn on a CD/DVD/BD and can then use to install Windows.

You will need to find that file yourself but what is legal in your country is yours to find out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to buy the installation disk - e.g. [Windows Home Premium @ Currys](http://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/computing-accessories/software/business-home-office/operating-systems/microsoft-windows-7-home-premium-03351305-pdt.html), which you can only install on a limited amount of computers, and it can be certain versions - e.g. Ultimate, Enterpise, Home Basic, etc. Windows, unlike Ubuntu, is not Open source, and cannot be downloaded and installed legally for free, as least not that easily, and most countries.

Then you can follow guides like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-to-create-a-windows-8-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu) to install Windows from a USB.

**Edit:**

The question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft) has download links.